# Jquery: Extract number from string and write to attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes

I have a form with a select element.
I am trying to figure out a way to extract the number ($ Dollar amount) from from the text and write it to the attribute - option value (so i can do some calculations).

What i have is this:

```
<select id="myselectbox" class="form-select">
  <option value="_none">- None -</option>
  <option value="7" selected="selected">An item - $1.99/ea</option>
  <option value="8">Another item - $2.89/ea</option>
</select>
```

What i want to see is:

```
  <option value="1.99" selected="selected">An item - $1.99/ea</option>
```

I am new to Jquery and javascript, so I would very much appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction! (or maybe even provide some example code! :)

Comment: Have you written/attempted ANY JavaScript/jQuery for this so far? If so, please provide.

Comment: So what you really want is for the value to be 1.99 instead of 7? So why not change the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('#myselectbox').find('option:gt(0)').each(function() {
        this.value = $(this).text().replace(/^.*\$([^\/]+)\/.*$/,'$1');
    });
    console.log( $('#myselectbox').html() );
});
```

Output:

```
  <option value="_none">- None -</option>
  <option value="1.99" selected="selected">An item - $1.99/ea</option>
  <option value="2.89">Another item - $2.89/ea</option>
```

[**WORKING JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/NyHQC/)

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly and simple. Exactly what i was expecting. :) For the sake of learning could you explain what the "gt(0)" is doing, and the "'$1'" at the end of character filter string.

Comment: Great! Glad it worked for you. Read `gt(0)` as **all but the first** -- that's just how to exclude `<option value='_none>....</option>`. In regular expressions we use `(....)` within the `/...../` of the regular expression to remember what was matched. The matches are remembered as `$1, $2, .... $9`. Therefore `$1` corresponds to the `first` (only one in our case) set of `(....)` in the regular expression -- which is `anything between the $ symbol and / character`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following jQuery script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function() {
        var options = jQuery("option");
        jQuery.each(options, function(index, value) {
            var value = jQuery(this).text();
            var re = /\$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|0)?\.[0-9]{1,2}/;
            var matches = value.match(re);

            if (matches) {
                var amount = matches[0].slice(1, matches[0].length - 1);
                jQuery(this).attr("value", amount);
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Here is the working demo @ [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Eder/g6BNr/6/)